# Increasing plot size with multiple plots?

Tags: python-3.x, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram with my data.
Using python on Jupyter notebook

```
    viz = cdf[['GyrNative', 'GyMutant', 'Hbond_native', 'HMutant', 'RMSDNative','RMSDMutant', 'RMSFNative', 'RMSFMutant', 'SASANative', 'SASAMutant']]
    plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
    viz.hist(grid=True, rwidth = 0.9, color ='red')
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=0.1)
    plt.show()
```

The plot generated are really tiny... How may I increase the size of each plot at once?

Comment: If you mean changing the sizes of individual plots, you should have a look at the `GridSpec` documentation and how to create the subplots of your figure using the `add_subplot()` method.

Comment: @Berenger I tried using, this instead  in accordance to the GridSpec docummentation, but this one plots only one graph rest are blank. Any specific reason why?                     
`viz = cdf[['GyrNative', 'GyMutant', 'Hbond_native', 'HMutant', 'RMSDNative','RMSDMutant', 'RMSFNative', 'RMSFMutant', 'SASANative', 'SASAMutant']]
viz.hist(grid=True, rwidth = 0.9, color ='red', ncols=4, nrows=3, constrained_layout=True)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=0.1)`

Comment: Hi @Kay, could you add some sample data for `viz`?

Comment: `+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| Col1e |  Col2t  |  Col3e  | Col4t | Col5e |  Col6t  |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|     0 | 1.51818 | 1.50145 | 128.0 |   141 | 100.228 |  98.491 |
|     1 | 1.51722 | 1.54022 | 126.0 |   130 |  99.562 |  99.428 |
|     2 | 1.51961 | 1.53201 | 139.0 |   139 | 100.269 |  99.956 |
|     3 | 1.51981 | 1.54077 | 137.0 |   123 | 100.230 | 100.788 |
|     4 | 1.52274 | 1.53873 | 127.0 |   126 |  98.788 | 101.350 |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+`

Comment: Thanks. I've added a potential solution for you. It's important to remember the order in which items are called and what the `.hist' call is doing in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the comments, if you just want to make the whole thing bigger, you should just add `figsize` to this and rearrange your `plt.` calls:

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.9, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=0.1)
viz.hist(grid=True, rwidth = 0.9, color ='red', figsize=(15,10))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on!  Thanks alot.

Comment: No probs -- grateful if you could accept the solution! :)

Comment: @Kay If it worked for you, please thank the person who helped you by accepting/upvoting their answer. You also get reputation for accepting the answers to your questions, and reputation gives you privileges on this site.

Comment: @Wiktor Done! Thanks